# Javax validation for local annotated variable

Tags: java, validation

How can I validate local variables with annotation?

```
@GoodsOrderGoodsParametersTableValidator
List<GoodsOrderGoodsParametersTableItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<List<GoodsOrderGoodsParametersTableItem>>> violations = validator.validate(result);
```

This code does not work, it just ignores the annotation

**Update:**

It works this way, but maybe some better way exists?

```
        GoodsOrderGoodsParametersRequest request = new GoodsOrderGoodsParametersRequest();
        request.setGoods(result);

        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<GoodsOrderGoodsParametersRequest>> violations = validator.validate(request);
        List<ConstraintViolation<GoodsOrderGoodsParametersRequest>> goodsViolations = violations
                .stream()
                .filter(violation -> violation.getPropertyPath().toString().equals("goods"))
                .toList();
```

Comment: It will work with javax validation only. Like Notnull Size

Comment: What is the use case here? Is it that you need to validate the list of `GoodsOrderGoodsParametersTableItem` as a whole, or just the individual elements? The latter should work with `List<@GoodsOrderGoodsParametersTableValidator GoodsOrderGoodsParametersTableItem>`

Comment: Yes I need to validate each element in this list with custom logics

Comment: What do you mean by local variables? Do you mean to say field members of a class or any local variables used in a method?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. You should clarify what do you want to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the Java Bean Validation framework (typically `Hibernate Validator`), annotations are usually put on fields, method return types, or type parameters (like the type inside collections). Local variables cannot be validated directly through annotations. That's the reason you need to wrap them inside an object to trigger the validation.

Your updated approach, where you wrap the list inside a request object, is indeed the common way to apply validations using annotations.

That said, if you often need to validate local variables or parameters, creating a helper method or utility might simplify and reduce the boilerplate in your code.

For example, you could create a utility function that performs the validation and filtering in one step:

```java
public static <T> List<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateProperty(T obj, String propertyName) {
    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = validator.validate(obj);
    return violations.stream()
            .filter(violation -> violation.getPropertyPath().toString().equals(propertyName))
            .toList();
}
```

Usage:

```java
GoodsOrderGoodsParametersRequest request = new GoodsOrderGoodsParametersRequest();
request.setGoods(result);
List<ConstraintViolation<GoodsOrderGoodsParametersRequest>> goodsViolations = validateProperty(request, "goods");
```

However, remember that validations can also be put on the class level if more complex, inter-field validations are needed.

It's also a good practice to use DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) for complex validations, especially if there's a mix of field and class-level constraints.

Lastly, while it may seem a bit more verbose, wrapping data inside objects for validation can make your code more maintainable and understandable in the long run. It clearly defines what the data is (through the object's class name and structure), and it centralizes the validation rules (through the annotations on the class's fields or methods).